# Moving for loop into a reduce method

Tags: python

I am trying to plot the location of ~4k postcodes onto a UK map, I am using a library that can take in the postcode and kick back latitude, longitude etc.., however the postcode must `always` contain a space before the last 3 characters in the string, for example:

```
'AF23 4FR' would be viable as the space is before the last 3 chars in the string..

'AF234FR' would not be allowed as there is no space..
```

I have to go over each item within my list and check there is a space before the n-3 position in the string, I can do this with a simple for loop but I would prefer to do this with a `reduce` function. I am struggling to workout how I would rework the check and logic of the following into a reduce method, would it even be worth it in this scenario:

```
for index, p in enumerate(data_set):
    if (p.find(' ') == -1):
        first = p[:len(p)]
        second = p[len(first):]
        data_set[index] = first + ' ' + second
```

Comment: Can't you 1) create a new string with spaces removed, 2) take everything to the last 3 characters of that, 3) the last 3 characters of that and then put a single space between 2 + 3?

Comment: So what you're doing now effectively but just start with `s = p.replace(' ', '')` -

Comment: A `reduce` will map a sequence into *one* value. How is this going to help you?

Comment: Why do you want to use `reduce` here? You current methods seems to be the optimal one, though you can use this syntax to get last 3 characters of the postcode: `p[-3:]`.

Comment: @KlausD. My aim was to run the above logic on certain indexes of my list, unless i have completely misunderstood the purpose of reduce, maybe I should have said map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much there... Create a generator with spaces removed from your string, then apply slicing and formatting, and use a list-comp to generate a new list of foramtted values, eg:

```
pcs_without_spaces = (pc.replace(' ', '') for pc in data_set)
formatted = ['{} {}'.format(pc[:-3], pc[-3:]) for pc in pcs_without_spaces)
```

That way, you don't need additional logic on whether it's got a space or not already in it, as long as your postcode is going to be valid after slicing, just removing the spaces and treating everything with the same logic is enough.